# Haskell, lambda calculus for Evaluation

Tags: haskell, types, lambda, lambda-calculus, evaluate

[image: Figure 1]

(Figure 1)

A part of the simply typed lambda calculus (Figure 1), it is implemented in Haskell as given below.

```
 evaluate expression = do
        case expression of
        (Application (Lambda x ltype term) value) | isValue value = True -> substitute term x value
        (Application value e2) | isValue value = True  -> let e22 = evaluate e2 in Application value e22
        (Application  e1 e2) -> let e11 = evaluate e1 in Application e11 e2
```

However, this doesn't work for these test cases,

1) `print (evaluate (Application (Var "x") (Var "y")))`

2) `print (evaluate (Application (Constant 3) (Var "y"))`   "(Constant 3) is a value"

But, for the first test case, I know it's because `(Var "x")` as `e1` is terminal so it cannot transition. Does it mean I should add a `Stuck` case? But I want to return an output suggesting the success of the transitions, if that's possible.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: A note on style, `x == True` is always redundant and can just be replaced with `x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're implementing your lambda calculus AST as something like

```
data Exp = Var String
         | Constant Int
         | App Exp Exp
         | Lam String Exp
```

then the interpreter `evaluate :: Exp -> Out` can produce a number of values, some the result of poorly typed input. For instance

```
evaluate (Lam "f" (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (Var "x")))
-- type like (a -> b) -> a -> b

evaluate (Var "x")
-- open term, evaluation gets stuck

evaluate (App (Lam "x" (Constant 4)) (Constant 3))
-- term results in a constant
```

We'll need to represent all of these types in the return type. A typical way to do that is to use a universal type like

```
data Out
  = Stuck
  | I Int
  | F (Out -> Out)
```

which again emphasizes the need for the stuck case. If we examine the `App` branch of `evaluate`

```
evaluate (App e1 e2) = case evaluate e1 of
  Stuck -> Stuck
  I i   -> Stuck
  F f   -> f (evaluate e2)
```

show's how `Stuck` cases both rise to the top and can arise from poorly typed terms.

---

There are many ways to write a well-typed simply-typed lambda calculus type in Haskell. I'm quite fond of the [Higher-Order Abstract Syntax Final Encoding](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/). It's wonderfully symmetric.

```
class STLC rep where
  lam :: (rep a -> rep b) -> rep (a -> b)
  app :: rep (a -> b) -> (rep a -> rep b)
  int :: Int -> rep Int

newtype Interpreter a = Reify { interpret :: a } -- just the identity monad

instance STLC Interpreter where
  lam f   = Reify $ interpret . f . Reify
  app f a = Reify $ interpret f $ interpret a
  int     = Reify
```

In this formulation, it's not possible at all to write a type of `STLC rep => rep a` which isn't well-typed and never-sticking. The type of `interpret` indicates this as well

```
interpret :: Interpreter a -> a
```

No `Out`-type in sight.

Comment: Thanks! for your last test case - `evaluate (App (Lam "x" (Constant 4)) (Constant 3))` - this should return `Constant 4` right? and therefore we must add the substitution method
 `substitute (Constant y) x s = Constant y`, were `s` is `Constant 4`

Comment: Actually, if you follow the example as I outlined it carefully you'll find you need substitute for Lam. But yes, the Haskell translation of that example is `const 4 $ 3 == 4`

Comment: Did you mean "lam f = Interpret (interpret . f . Interpret)"?

Comment: @AndrásKovács Yep, thanks! Fixed now while cutting down on some of the "interpret" noise.

Answer (score 0):

But, how `substitute` works then (i.e. what is the implementation of the `substitute` function in haskell).